# extending AngularJS's $error to show server side form validation errors

Tags: angularjs, validation

I am thinking of returning a `validationErrors` JSON object with the structure of `controlName.$error` from the server and then on the handler of the server API calling angular.extend(myform,data.validationErrors).

specifically I am not sure when and how will those errors be cleared... (maybe returning nulls for valid fields would help i.e. `{ctrl.$error:null,ctrl2.$error:null,...}`  [in this case maybe `validationResults` would be more suitable then `validationErrors`

Is there a common practice on how to display server side validation errors for AngularJS forms?
Does this sound reasonable and in angular spirit or am I going to have trouble with this?